# Add Input Text Field in the php form and store data in file also show that text in Dynamic Table

Tags: php, forms

I Have created a Program (Doctors on Leave Add/Remove Dynamically) which selects the dates from the user then select which doctor to leave and Now I want to add text input field for remarks & also show it in a table from the file I'm saving the content in..
Can Anyone help me with that please

This is my code

```
<?php
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$data = $_POST["doctorName"].";".$_POST["leaveFrom"].";".$_POST["leaveTo"].";";
$fp = fopen('file-path', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
header("Location: #");
exit();
}
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
if(array_key_exists("n", $_GET)){
    $newNames = "";
    $filename = "file-path";
    $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $arr_del = explode(";", $lines[0]);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr_del)-1; $i++){
        if($arr_del[$i] == $_GET["n"]){
            $i = $i+2;
        } else {
            $newNames .= $arr_del[$i].";";
        }
    }
    $fp = fopen('file-path', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $newNames);
    fclose($fp);
    header("Location: #");
    exit();
    }
    }
    ?>

    <html>
    <body>


    <center><h2>Doctor on Leave</h2></center>
    <?php 
      $data = file_get_contents("file-path");
        $arr = explode(";", $data);
        echo "<table style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">";
        echo "<thead>";
            echo "<tr style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">";
                    echo "<th style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">Doctor Name</th>";
                    echo "<th style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">Delete</th>";
                    echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";
                for($value = 0; $value < count($arr)-1; $value=$value+3) {
                    echo "<tr style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">";
                    echo "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">".$arr[$value]."</td>";
                    echo "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">"."<button id=\"".$arr[$value]."\" 
                    onclick=\"deleteDoctor(this.id)\" style=\"background-color: red; 
                    color:white\">Delete</button>"."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";    
         ?>
         <form action="/" method="POST">
      <label>Select the Doctor </label><br>
      <select name="doctorName" style="width:300px;">
      <option value="Dr. Ankur Mittal">Dr. Ankur Mittal</option>
      <option value="Dr. Anooj Chatley">Dr. Anooj Chatley</option>
      <option value="Dr. Arti Gupta Tuli">Dr. Arti Gupta Tuli</option>
      <option value="Dr. Ashok Goyal">Dr. Ashok Goyal</option>
      <option value="Dr. H.S. Bindra">Dr. H.S. Bindra</option>



      </select>
        <br><br>
      <p>From</p>
           <input type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="leaveFrom" name="leaveFrom" 
        placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" style="width:fit-content;">
        <br><br>
        <p>To</p>
          <input type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="leaveTo" name="leaveTo"  
        placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" style="width:fit-content;">
       <br><br><input type="submit">
       </form>

        <script>
        function deleteDoctor(name){
        location.href= "#?n="+name;
        }
        </script>

    


       </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code, It should work.
Changes I have done

1. Append $_POST['remarks'] in $data at line 3
2. Changed `$i = $i+2;` to `$i = $i+3;` at line 18, to remove newly added field. If you plan to add more fields in future, just increment this number by 1 every time
3. Added 3 columns in html table head (From, To and Remarks)
4. Printed values of From, To and Remarks on line 52, 53 and 54.

   ```
   echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$arr[$value+1].'</td>';
   echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$arr[$value+2].'</td>';
   echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$arr[$value+3].'</td>';
   ```

   When you add more fields, just do it by incrementing 1
5. Lastly added a new input box at bottom `<input type="text" id="remarks" name="remarks" placeholder="Remarks" style="width:fit-content;">`

Feel free to comment if any problem with the updated code

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $data = $_POST["doctorName"].";".$_POST["leaveFrom"].";".$_POST["leaveTo"].";".$_POST["remarks"].";";
    $fp = fopen('file-path', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
    header("Location: #");
    exit();
}
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    if(array_key_exists("n", $_GET)){
        $newNames = "";
        $filename = "file-path";
        $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        $arr_del = explode(";", $lines[0]);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($arr_del)-1; $i++){
            if($arr_del[$i] == $_GET["n"]){
                $i = $i+3;
            } else {
                $newNames .= $arr_del[$i].";";
            }
        }
        $fp = fopen('file-path', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $newNames);
        fclose($fp);
        header("Location: #");
        exit();
    }
}
?>

<html>
<body>
    <center><h2>Doctor on Leave</h2></center>
    <?php 
    $data = file_get_contents("file-path");
    $arr = explode(";", $data);
    echo '<table style="border: 1px solid black;">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr style="border: 1px solid black;">';
    echo '<th style="border: 1px solid black;">Doctor Name</th>';
    echo '<th style="border: 1px solid black;">From</th>';
    echo '<th style="border: 1px solid black;">To</th>';
    echo '<th style="border: 1px solid black;">Remarks</th>';
    echo '<th style="border: 1px solid black;">Delete</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';
    for($value = 0; $value < count($arr)-1; $value=$value+4) {
        echo '<tr style="border: 1px solid black;">';
        echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$arr[$value].'</td>';
        echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$arr[$value+1].'</td>';
        echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$arr[$value+2].'</td>';
        echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$arr[$value+3].'</td>';
        echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'.'<button id="".$arr[$value]."" 
        onclick="deleteDoctor(this.id)" style="background-color: red; 
        color:white">Delete</button>'.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';    
    ?>
    <form action="asd.php" method="POST">
        <label>Select the Doctor </label><br>
        <select name="doctorName" style="width:300px;">
            <option value="Dr. Ankur Mittal">Dr. Ankur Mittal</option>
            <option value="Dr. Anooj Chatley">Dr. Anooj Chatley</option>
            <option value="Dr. Arti Gupta Tuli">Dr. Arti Gupta Tuli</option>
            <option value="Dr. Ashok Goyal">Dr. Ashok Goyal</option>
            <option value="Dr. H.S. Bindra">Dr. H.S. Bindra</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <p>From</p>
        <input type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="leaveFrom" name="leaveFrom" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" style="width:fit-content;">
        <br><br>
        <p>To</p>
        <input type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="leaveTo" name="leaveTo" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" style="width:fit-content;">
        <br><br>
        <p>Remarks</p>
        <input type="text" id="remarks" name="remarks" placeholder="Remarks" style="width:fit-content;">
        <br><br><input type="submit">
    </form>

    <script>
        function deleteDoctor(name){
            location.href= "#?n="+name;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, Code It is working Fine However I'm Facing One issue that now file content is not deleting when clicking Delete Button It was working before. what's wrong with that

Comment: I think you should empty your file and try again by adding new rows. As you are using file based storage with semi colon separator. You had 3 fields previously now have 4 fields, this might create issue in existing file. Try with empty file.
And if it works, please remember to mark it as accepted answer :)